# Java key event doesn't work

Tags: java, events, key

I am trying to understand Java events but I have a problem with the key event. In my code the key event doesn't work. The problem occurs when I create this line `add(button);` (I think so). What should I do?

Code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;



public class KeyTest extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    static JButton button;
    private int counter = 0;
    private String userInput = "";
    private final String secret = "secret";

    public KeyTest() {
        super("KeyListener Test");
        addKeyListener(this);
        ActionListener lol = new Akcja();
        button = new JButton("tura");
        button.addActionListener(lol);
        add(button);
        pack();
        Dimension dimension = new Dimension(400, 400);
        setPreferredSize(dimension);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
        char c = evt.getKeyChar();
        if(counter < secret.length())
            checkSecret(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {

    }

    private void checkSecret(char c) {
        if(c == secret.charAt(counter)) {
            counter++;
            userInput = userInput+c;
        }
        else {
            counter = 0;
            userInput = userInput+c;

        }


            setTitle(userInput);
    }
    static class Akcja implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //to-do
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: please be elaborate about the problem. What error or warning you are getting?

Comment: It doesn't change window title. And when I debug  program doesn't enter enkeyReleased(); .

Comment: No errors and no warnings.

Comment: Maybe they jframe does not have focus, or is not configured to accept key presses?  Maybe try adding the keylistener to the button, instead?